# how can I match these regular expressions?

Tags: mysql, regex, laravel

I have a url stored in a database. From a given url, i have to fetch data from the database but I'm confused how can I indentify the actual url. It's confusing when the url from the user is dynamic like text or a number.
example:

```
/user                   should match the url       /user
/user/1                 should match the url       /user/{id}
/user/name/johndoe      should match the url       /user/name/{name}
/user/1/johndoe         should match the url       /user/{id}/{name}
```

I have tried this one it works for /user/1 i.e with integers but I cannot make it work with string. There's no way to indentify the string parameters. Or is there other way in mysql a workaround.

> **MOTO:**   Fetch the content from the database where a given url string matches the url column. Note: the {id}, {name}, {type} are dynamic values.

Controller:

```
$sanitizedUrl = preg_replace('/\/*\d{1,}/','/{id}', '/user/name/1');
UrlContent::where('url', $sanitizedUrl)->first()->content;
```

> This code can only work with the urls which have numbers only. Example: /user/12/type/12 is replaced as /user/{id}/type/{id}

Database : url_contents

```
|     url                |  content    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| /user/name/{id}        | matches if url is /user/name/1 |
| /user/{id}/{name}      | if url is /user/1/john         |
| /user/{type}/{name}    | if url i /user/{type}/{name}   |
```

Comment: I'm also confused.  What are you trying to match here?

Comment: Where have you matched the URL? In controller? Please add full controller code in the question.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I have update the question with the controller get as well as a proto of my db

Comment: How many urls do you have in mysql table that corresponds to `UrlContent` model?

Comment: its like how much page urls does a site have? All site page urls are stored in the url_contents table

Comment: How many currently?

Comment: @revo 25 rows in url_contents

Comment: Then fetch all those rows and run your `preg_replace` on them and build your regex. Then use that regex to match the initial url.

Comment: hmm sound good. Can you show me one regex example please to match the urls. That I've included in the question database section. @revo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it the other way:

```
function getUrlContent($url)
{
    $replacements = [
        '{id}' => '\d+',
        '{name}' => '\w+',
    ];

    $urlContents = UrlContent::all();
    foreach ($urlContents as $urlContent) {
        if (preg_match('~' . strtr($urlContent->url, $replacements) . '~', $url)) {
            return $urlContent->content;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$url = '/user/1/johndoe';

var_dump(getUrlContent($url));
```

Also you may need to cache all built regular expressions for a time to reduce  mysql overhead of a roundtrip. If `url_contents` table grows significantly you may have to add another column which will contain the regular expression itself:

```
+-----------------+----------------+------------+
|       url       |    url_regex   |   content  |
+-----------------+----------------+------------+
| /user/name/{id} | /user/name/\d+ |  ......... |
+-----------------+----------------+------------+
```